# SQL Select error and OUTPUT

Tags: sql-server, database, select-query

I need to query a database for some information and then store it into a .csv file in case the dispatch system goes down. I'm running into some issues with the `select` query as well as the `output` statement. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT cmpy, veh, driver, attendant, trainee, unit_code, startdate 
FROM vehicle_schedule 
WHERE startdate >= 2015-07-22
ORDER BY cmpy, veh
```

The error that I am getting is this:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2010-05-25' to data type int.
```

I'm not sure what is going on and exactly how to fix the issue. Also I can't get it to output to a file, I get the error: `incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'`

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: put the start date in where condition in '2015-07-22' and cast ('2015-07-22' as varchar)

Comment: You are missing single quotes around the date.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? Also, SQL is a special-purpose programming language mainly used to interact with databases and is not a general purpose, object-oriented one that interacts with external objects and file formats. Hence, you will need some other coding language (Java, Python, PHP, VB, etc.) to output this query to csv. While I say this some dialects like MySQL's `outfile` and PostgreSQL's `Copy` have workarounds.

Comment: @Parfait I know that part, I'm using C# to write a script to run every 15 min to query the db in case our dispatching system goes down. So `sql server` does not support an output method?

Comment: Forgive me but then why not use [C# to save the query to csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963719/c-sharp-sqlserver-retrieving-results-and-place-in-a-csv-format)? You also avoid having to run a procedure in MSSQL to export the data if possible. As mentioned, abstract your external data processes from internal data handling. Remember a client app like your C# script has a very short lifecycle compared to a database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  You are missing single quotes for the date constant:

```
 WHERE startdate >= '2015-07-22'
```

The error you are getting is because 2015-07-22 = 1986 (they hyphens are interpreted as minus signs), so the query is turned into:

```
WHERE startdate >= 1986
```

Because of the comparison to an integer, SQL Server attempts to convert `startdate` to an integer . . . and you get a relatively unintelligible error.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I didn't realize it thought it was 1986. Do you have anything for the output part?

Comment: @WilliamHodges . . . The query in your question does not have an `OUTPUT` clause.  In fact, there is  no `OUTPUT` clause for `SELECT` queries, so you should just google:  "sql server output query to file" and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

you missed quotes around the date

try this

```
SELECT cmpy, veh, driver, attendant, trainee, unit_code, startdate 
FROM vehicle_schedule 
WHERE startdate >= '2015-07-22'
ORDER BY cmpy, veh
```

Comment: that fixed the select statement, thank you for your help, do you have a tip on the output part?

Comment: check this link
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/