# Generate a SQL data sheet with button click (Visual Studio + SQL Server)?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ssms, datasheet

Is there a way you can generate all the data from a specific database table as a data sheet using a button click in ***C#***? 
Is this possible using ***Visual Studio*** and ***SSMS***?
Thank you,

Comment: What's a "data sheet" in this context?

Comment: What kind of datasheet! Post your expected output

Comment: Like a table with the name of the columns and the data that a user can download locally not just show it like datagrids. Is this possible?

Comment: You basically want `.sql` of the database

Comment: Do you want something like an excel spread sheet?

Comment: Please can you explain and can you change that into a pdf file? Thank you for your feedback,

Comment: @DaveBecker yes like that. is it possible?

Comment: The easiest way would be to export the data to a `.csv` and import into excel. There are shed loads of posts on how to do this, this is just one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963719/c-sharp-sqlserver-retrieving-results-and-place-in-a-csv-format

Comment: If you want a datasheet you can generate a report in SQL Server which is a web applicaton.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/reporting-services-report-server-sharepoint-mode